# Confused on some oop object passing issues

Tags: oop, object

I was thinking about passing an object to another object, and how it can get complicated. If object A and object B are created in the main class, and object A creates object C, how can I pass object C to object B? Or should I never create an object in another object and therefore never get too far away from the main class?

This got me thinking of a situation in which this might occur, but couldn't exactly match it up in my head, but I thought, what if I create two objects, and have a class that determines collision based on location properties of the objects. In the main class I can pass the two objects to the collision class, and then in the main class I can do some work based on the result. This makes sense, but is this the best way to find collision? Or should I make the collision class static?

Thanks for any replies to the two questions, sorry for not being more specific but I'm trying to wrap my head around the oop concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are thinking of is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). You are not the first one to think at this kind of problem of course.

Most of recent OOP frameworks handle that dependency injection for you. An example of implementation is to use configured services (SOA) in specific configuration files (JSON, YML, XML, ...) referencing your classes. Then the framework will instantiate all your services in the right dependency order for you!

If you want to code it by your own, you certainly should code a `dependencyInjectionHandler` or `servicesContainer` which do all the process of injecting objects into each others.

If you come from the PHP world, you can look at an implementation on [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) for example.
Prefer Javascript? Take a look at [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf).
You should be able to find at least one existing implementation in almost all recent languages.

Answer (score 0):

As the Dependency injection principle tells us - you should never create a Dependency (in you're case Object C)  in your object, if you want to use another object you should inject it to the dependant object, this is called - inversion of control, the most popular and best practice is to inject you're dependencies in the constructor.
As to where you create them - like you suggested create them at the top (you're main function as you said)  of you're a code and inject them all the way down. Depending on the language and framework you are using you can find lots of tools to help you manage it it a bigger scale app's - those tools usually called DI containers.

Good luck.